# Using GNU Make with subdirectories

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I was wondering what different approaches of using Make in a project with subdirectories exist, and what are their advantages/drawbacks, but could never see a good summary or cookbook.

I have seen in my researches mainly the "recursive" and "single makefile" approaches, but are there others ?

I also assume that there is not only one "recursive" or "single makefile" approaches but several, so could somebody sum it up ?

For my particular case, I would like a directory architecture looking like this:

```
.
├── build
│   ├── *.d
│   ├── *.o
|   ├── subdir1
|   │   ├── *.d
|   │   └── *.o
|   └── subdir2
|       ├── *.d
|       ├── *.o
|       └── subdir3
|           ├── *.d
|           └── *.o
├── include
│   ├── *.h
│   └── *.h
├── Makefile
└── src
    ├── *.c
    ├── *.h
    ├── subdir1
    │   ├── *.c
    │   └── *.h
    └── subdir2
        ├── *.c
        ├── *.h
        └── subdir3
            ├── *.c
            └── *.h
```

Which solution should I choose ? Possibly one which would allow source files with the same name ?

Comment: The basic arguments against recursive make are laid out in the [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf)(pdf) paper. [This page](http://evbergen.home.xs4all.nl/nonrecursive-make.html) talks about implementing a non-recursive make system as does this [Painless non-recursive Make](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/article/painless-non-recursive-make) article. The [Multi-Architecture Builds](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/multi-architecture-builds/) article also has some relevant things to say on this topic I believe.

Comment: Recursive and single-makefile pretty much cover it, but of course you can mix them -- have the master makefile call `src/Makefile` which then handles the entire `src/` tree on its own.

Comment: There are arguments both ways.  Startup time with the non-recursive make can be costly (when I first built glibc it took almost an hour to get started). The papers promoting nonrecursive makes dismiss this issue or completely forget to mention it.  Given that, the question is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf), I figured a quite simple and modular way to achieve this, by having files in all subdirectories that would include each other and be included in the main makefile:

```
CXX         := gcc

SRCDIR          := src
OBJDIR          := build

# These lines are needed to set immediate evaluation for
# these variables, instead of deferred evaluation which is unsuitable.
SRCS            :=
SUBDIRS         :=
CFLAGS          :=
LDFLAGS         :=

include $(SRCDIR)/module.mk

OBJS            := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(SRCS:.c=.o))

SRCS            := $(addprefix $(SRCDIR)/, $(SRCS))

DEPS            := $(OBJS:.o=.d)

TMPS            := $(OBJS) $(OBJS:.o=.d)

CFLAGS          += -MD
debug: CFLAGS   += -g -g3 -ggdb
CFLAGS          += $(addprefix -I./$(SRCDIR)/, $(SUBDIRS))

LDFLAGS         += -lsomelib
debug: LDFLAGS      += -g -g3 -ggdb

NAME            := yolo

all: $(NAME)

debug:  re

-include $(DEPS)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

$(NAME): $(OBJS)
    @$(CXX) $(OBJS) -o $(NAME) $(LDFLAGS)

$(OBJS): | $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR):
    @mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
    @for dir in $(SUBDIRS);         \
    do                  \
        mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)/$$dir;   \
    done

clean:
    rm -rf $(TMPS)

fclean: clean
    rm -rf $(NAME)
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR)

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all clean fclean re
```

And in every subdirectory, a module.mk file (I could have named it anything, but this seemde cool).

For src:

```
SRCS        :=  main.c file1.c file2.c

SUBDIRS     +=  subdir1 subdir2

include $(SRCDIR)/subdir1/module.mk
include $(SRCDIR)/subdir2/module.mk
```

For a level 1 subdirectory:

```
THIS_DIR_L0 := subdir1

MOD_SRC     :=  file3.c file4.c

SRCS        += $(addprefix $(THIS_DIR_L0)/, $(MOD_SRC))

SUBDIRS     += $(THIS_DIR_L0)/subdir3

include $(SRCDIR)/$(THIS_DIR_L0)/subdir3/module.mk
```

And for a level 2 subdir (one deeper):

```
THIS_DIR_L1 := subdir3

MOD_SRC     :=  file5.c file6.c

SRCS        += $(addprefix $(THIS_DIR_L0)/$(THIS_DIR_L1)/, $(MOD_SRC))
```

And so on...

This is quite simple to set up, I find it very modular and it does not use recursive makefiles. It would not be complicated to make librairies and stuff inside your directory structure either.

Anybody having a better idea please tell me.

Answer (score 2):

Your project setup is really basic, so should be your Makefile:

```make
SRC_DIR := src
BLD_DIR := build

SRC := $(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -name "*.c")
OBJ := $(SRC:$(SRC_DIR)/%.c=$(BLD_DIR)/%.o)
DEP := $(OBJ:.o=.d)

CPPFLAGS := -MMD -MP # enable auto-dependency generation
CFLAGS   := -Wall -W -pedantic

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(OBJ)

clean:
    $(RM) -r $(BLD_DIR)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(BLD_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c | $$(@D)/ # First check that the destination directory exists
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

%/:
    mkdir -p $* # -p flag necessary for recursive directory creation

ifeq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" ""
-include $(DEP)
endif
```

The idea here is to list source files recursively using the `find` command, to supply make with the appropriate pattern rule to compile in the right place and pass the right preprocessor file to your compiler to enable auto-dependency generation.

---

Tested with GNU Make 4.1 under Windows 8.1 with the GIT Bash shell and the following directory structure:

```
.
├── Makefile
└── src
    ├── test.c
    ├── test1.c
    └── subdir1
        └── test.c
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, as it would work for my problem. My only concern with that method is that I do not define my source files in some specific places but instead juste take everything which is out there indistinctively. Sometimes it is not desirable.

Comment: The way you list your source files is up to you in the end, you can do it manually, but even if you do need to list specific files only, my technique lets you write one small single Makefile and all you need to update is `SRC` since every project structure change is already covered, whereas your solution requires a file for each directory, and changes to your different includes throughout the filesystem. To me, my Makefile is more modular, and even way smaller than everything your answer promotes.